# How much native functionality is required for Apple app store approval?

Tags: ios, app-store

We've made an application that embeds some web content, which has been approved before. Recently Apple has begun rejecting these app's stating that they're plain content-aggregators and that they lack native functionality, even though they have native functionality such as push notifications and reachability checks.

We now considered splitting the web views up and make a native UITabBar.

The question now is—does any of you have any experience whether or not this sort of app would be approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will also depend on the reviewer. I once got an application accepted, and the update wasn't accepted because I did not gave an access account (although when I first submitted, the reviewer, did created one to test). Try adding the UITabBar so you can have a more native look, but perhaps, they do have a check a list, at least as a guide line to see if  an application does have a native look.

Answer (score 0):

> they're plain content-aggregators and that they lack native
>   functionality

By this apple means that if you can easily show your data using a mobile website then don't create a native app for this.

```
2.12

Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
```

see here - https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html